# Check if a primary key exists in an SqlAlchemy Session

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'd like to be able to check if an object with a given primary key exists in a `Session` object.

This is similar to the `get` function, which operates like:

```
  > session.get({primary key})
    ... if {primary key} is in the session, return that object
    ... otherwise issue the SQL to check if the primary key is in the database
    ... if the primary key is in the database return that object otherwise None
```

I simply want to get the object if it's in the session without emitting any SQL.

(The reason for this is for my application I know that if the object is not already in the session it won't be in the database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if an object with a given primary key is in a session by looking it up in the session's `identity_map`.

The keys of the identity map are "identity key" tuples, which you can generate with the `sqlalchemy.orm.util.identity_key` function.

For example, given a mapped class `MyClass` with a primary key `id`, to check a session for an object with the id of 99:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.util import identity_key
my_key = identity_key(MyClass, 99)
# will return the instance of MyClass in the session, or None
my_class_instance = my_session.identity_map.get(my_key)
```

Source: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.identity_map